How to Keep a Camera Stream Active Across Pages Without Reinitializing the Camera on Each Page?
I am working on a web application that requires a live camera stream to stay active across multiple pages. The stream is displayed at the top of each page, but currently, the camera stops and reinitializes every time the user navigates to a new page.
I want users to be able to navigate between pages without restarting the camera or causing interruptions in the stream. Ideally, I’d prefer solutions other than converting the site into a Single Page Application (SPA), but I am open to it if it’s the best option.
The web app is built using Flask framework and HTML. I'm using OpenCV to handle the camera and the image processing.

What tech stack are you working with?

I use OpenCV in Python to handle the camera and image processing, Flask framework, HTML, JavaScript, and CSS.


"Ideally, I’d prefer solutions other than converting the site into a Single Page Application (SPA), but I am open to it if it’s the best option."

You can try using iframe to load the website as a separate thing from the <video>.
Next you can display both at same time by using layers (eg: the CSS z-index option).
Example code: 
(when Running, click "Full Page" to see the solution in action properly)


<!-- loads and contains the website (is index.html ???) -->
<!-- puts it on layer 1 via "z-index: 1" -->
<iframe src="https://lumiere-video.github.io/" width="98%" height="700" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 9px">
</iframe>

<!-- loads and contains the video tag -->
<!-- puts it on layer 2 via "z-index: 2" -->
<!-- keep it always on screen via "position: sticky" -->
<video width="320" height="240" controls muted loop autoplay
style="z-index: 2; position: sticky; top: 0px; left: 0px">
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>



